# Как лучше реализовать модуль в js?

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Задумался вот о чём: на сайтах по js написано, что лучше всего реализовывать модуль через такой приём:

```js
;(function() {

 //тело модуля

})();
```

Но как я понимаю, может сработать и обычной `addEventListener`, то есть

```js
window.addEventListener ("load", function () {

  //тело модуля

});
```

Какой метод лучше использовать?

Comment: Еще так можно `!function() {....}();`

Comment: Безусловно, перед модулем можно что угодно поставить (плюс, на пример), но какой метод лучше использовать?

Comment: Особой разницы нет. За исключением вашего 2 варианта, где сначала дергается `addEventListener `, а только потом дергается анонимная функция. Но еще в новых стандартах делается так:`(()=>{ ... })();`

Comment: Но если мне нужно, чтобы модуль исполнялся после загрузки страницы, это же нормальный вариант?

Comment: Вполне нормально.

Comment: Сначала нужно определиться, что ты понимаешь под модулем. В примере у тебя нет модулей, если две функции - одна вызывается сразу при объявлении, вторая - по событию.

Comment: @And __Но еще в новых стандартах делается так:(()=>{ ... })();__ про это я не знал.Можете показать пример или ссылку пожалуйста ?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, читайте про стрелочные функции.

Comment: @And да я читал и знаю про стрелочные функции но про модулной проектировании там не было.Спасибо все равно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти оба варианты могут быть. Однако плюсы второго в том, что не важно положения скрипта в документе, он должен без проблем работать. Например, это помогает в случае, если скрипт подключен выше(первее), чем необходимые для работы компоненты(скрипты, html элементы и т.п)